Why slice may affect the torch.nn.linear output?
I am curious why the following code will return False. In torch, slice seems to affect the linear layer output. Thanks for your attention~
torch.manual_seed(1234)
a = torch.randn((50, 4096)).float()
idx = [0, 2]
b = a[idx,:]
w1 = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 4096, bias=False)
w2 = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 4096, bias=False)
w3 = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 4096, bias=False)

act = torch.nn.SiLU()
out_a = w3(act(w1(a)) * w2(a))
out_b = w3(act(w1(b)) * w2(b))
print(torch.equal(out_a[idx,:], out_b))

In the above test, the outputs of out_a[idx,:] and out_b are very closed but different, like 0.0507067293 and 0.0507068783.

It's happening because floating point arithmetic is not associative, i.e for any any three floating point variables a, b, c, it is possible that (a + b) + c != a + (b+ c)
Note that already w1(a)[idx, :] is not equal to w1(b)
